# Getting all 10 digit and 9 digit number for a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm a new bee to the python.So all I want is to get all the 10 digit number and 9 digit number from a string.
I'm having a string Like this

```
Re: ehi - ECQ TANGAL INIP NA!!!! 67778877 NO LOAD 34567890123!!!! 5678901234 123456789
```

Should return only the numbers with 9 and 10 digit.The number can occur anywhere in the string.
In the above string it should return these numbers

```
5678901234 
123456789
```

But not

```
67778877 as it is 8 digit number 
34567890123 as it is 11 digit number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to find all required matches:

```
import re

data = 'Re: ehi - ECQ TANGAL INIP NA!!!! 67778877 NO LOAD 34567890123!!!! 5678901234 123456789'
values = re.findall(r'\b\d{9,10}\b', data)
print( values )  # ['5678901234', '123456789']
```

Here `\b` states for the boundary of the numeric group `\d` (same as `[0-9]`). `{9,10}` is the number of repetitions of `\d`.

**DOCS:** https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html